# org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException

Tags: java, spring

I create such bean:

```
<bean id="settings" class="Settings">
    <property name="path" value="${path}"/>
</bean>
```

Here is class definition:

```
public class Settings {
   private String path;

   public String getPath() { return path; }
   public void setPath(String path) { this.path = path; }
}
```

And I try run maven project using `-Dpath=c:\ clean test` command. Everything is fine but instead of `c:\` I have `"${path}"` (takes it as a string not as a parameter to replace). When I give this path directly in bean:

```
<bean id="settings" class="Settings">
    <property name="path" value="c:\\"/>
</bean>
```

everything works fine.

Where is the problem?

Comment: add `<context:property-placeholder />`.

Comment: Can you explain more? After add it to xml file with beans I got "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:property-placeholder'"

Comment: Please, post all the xml

Comment: Only adding the xml will not work you will also need to add the xsd to the schema location.

Comment: "add the xsd to the schema location" - what is xsd and where I find scheme location, on the top?